# CakePHP 2: 301 Router:redirect not working

Tags: redirect, cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-2.0

I can't seem to 301 redirect a link for my cakePHP v2 website.
What I am doing is this:

```
//routes.php file

Router::connect('/how-to-make-extra-income-online', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'how_to_make_extra_income_online'));

Router::redirect('/how-to-make-extra-income-online', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'how_to_make_extra_income_online'), array('persistent' => true, 'status' => 301));
```

I've tried placing redirect before connect but that doesn't work either.

While debugging, I found out the if I change the redirect to a url different from the one used in connect and then I run that url, the redirect does give a 301 redirect for example changing this:

```
Router::redirect('/how-to-make-extra-income-online', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'how_to_make_extra_income_online'), array('persistent' => true, 'status' => 301));
```

to this:

```
Router::redirect('/abc', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'how_to_make_extra_income_online'), array('persistent' => true, 'status' => 301));
```

For the above example if type "/abc" in URL it will redirect to "/how-to-make-extra-income-online" but then if I add it to a button etc, it won't call the Router:redirect.

Adding it to the button code:

```
<li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Test1', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'how_to_make_extra_income_online')); ?></li>
```

Any solution?

Note: Apology if this is a little confusing.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the code where you're trying "add it to a button etc"?

Comment: @GregSchmidt I've added it in the question above.

Comment: Seems that you should only need one or the other of `connect` and `redirect`, but I'm not an expert in this area, or Cake 2. When you create the link with the shown code, what result do you get, and how does it differ from your expectation?

Comment: If I use only connect, it works but I do not get a 301 redirection rather I get a 302 redirect which shouldn't happen. If I use only redirect, I doesn't work at all.